# Eigen function in R programming

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Consider the square of A using `eigen()` function in `R`.

We know that, for A = V x D x V^(-1) then A^n = V x D^n x V^(-1), where columns of V contains the eigenvectors of A and D is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of A on the diagonal.

```
`                [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
           [1,]    1    5    9   13
           [2,]    2    6   10   14
A =        [3,]    3    7   11   15
           [4,]    4    8   12   16    `
```

The result should be same as A*A

```
`     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   90  202  314  426
 [2,]  100  228  356  484
 [3,]  110  254  398  542
 [4,]  120  280  440  600    `
```

I have tried

```
V <- eigen(A)$vectors
square_dia <- diag(eigen(A)$values,4,4)
D <- diag(A)*diag(A)
```

But I couldn't get the result I desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do get these results matching.  Perhaps you confused `%*%` (matrix product) with `*` (elementwise/Hadamard product) somewhere?

```
V <- eigen(A)$vectors
D <- diag(eigen(A)$values)
M1 <- V %*% D^2 %*% solve(V)
M2 <- A %*% A
all.equal(M1, M2) ## TRUE
```

You may be interested in the `%^%` (matrix power) operator from the `expm` package ...

Comment: If this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept the answer ...